# Hanging Indents in Tables for Equations

Tags: tables, equations, vertical-alignment, indentation

I currently have the following code

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|p{5in}}
Differential Equation & $(1273628x^{4} + 1237129387x^{3} + 12831729x^{2})f'''(x)
   + (9x^{3} + 12392183012938120x^{2} + x)f'(x) + 120938120xf(x) = 0$\\\hline
Notes & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam imperdiet, 
nunc ac euismod adipiscing, arcu erat pellentesque turpis, a tincidunt velit 
est sed sem. Proin dolor purus, eleifend vel pellentesque sit amet, lobortis 
non nibh. Duis in lacus eget odio varius interdum. Fusce pretium lectus sit 
amet metus molestie sit amet mollis ante viverra. Fusce eget augue vitae elit 
blandit facilisis. Nullam ultrices felis quis magna dignissim auctor. Cras 
dignissim porttitor nisl, id viverra sapien ornare ac. Proin adipiscing, dui 
at tempor faucibus, purus lacus aliquet nulla, ac dictum arcu erat nec felis. 
Aliquam rutrum nunc nec ligula euismod scelerisque. Nam interdum tincidunt 
tellus id malesuada. Pellentesque id elit nibh, vel scelerisque turpis. Proin 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

How do I get Notes centered with respect to the height of the Lorem ipsum paragraph and how does one do a hanging indent on the equation in the differential equation row?

Comment: In general, if you have two different questions, even regarding the same code, please post two separate questions. This allows specific answers and choosing for each the best answer to accept, hardly possible with different partial answers otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For vertical centering use the `array` package and an `m` column.
- For the equation I recommend using a multi line environment of `amsmath`, such as `multline*` or `\align*` or an aligned formula block in inline math mode, if you wish to avoid vertical space around.

Here's an example with `alignedat` from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|m{4in}}
Differential Equation & $\begin{alignedat}{1}
  (1273628x^{4} + 1237129387x^{3} + 12831729x^{2})f'''(x)& \\
   + (9x^{3} + 12392183012938120x^{2} + x)f'(x)&\\
   + 120938120xf(x) &= 0
  \end{alignedat}$\\\hline
Notes & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam imperdiet, 
nunc ac euismod adipiscing, arcu erat pellentesque turpis, a tincidunt velit 
est sed sem. Proin dolor purus, eleifend vel pellentesque sit amet, lobortis 
non nibh. Duis in lacus eget odio varius interdum. Fusce pretium lectus sit 
amet metus molestie sit amet mollis ante viverra. Fusce eget augue vitae elit 
blandit facilisis. Nullam ultrices felis quis magna dignissim auctor. Cras 
dignissim porttitor nisl, id viverra sapien ornare ac. Proin adipiscing, dui 
at tempor faucibus, purus lacus aliquet nulla, ac dictum arcu erat nec felis. 
Aliquam rutrum nunc nec ligula euismod scelerisque. Nam interdum tincidunt 
tellus id malesuada. Pellentesque id elit nibh, vel scelerisque turpis. Proin 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: table with equation]